# Is there a way to get images found in device gallery on flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

I am trying to fetch images from a device's gallery and display them on my own customized screen for users to select (multiple images). I have used photo manager but its performance has been very slow. is there another way to do it? or should I write it in Kotlin and integrate it into my flutter app?

Comment: You can use `image_picker` package to open gallery and get your image from there. https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

Comment: that package allows you to select one image. what i want is for the user to select certain amount of images.

Comment: Then you can use `wechat_asset_picker` for that this package has a number of functions with selecting multiple images to multiple videos. https://pub.dev/packages/wechat_assets_picker

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker2 that will do the trick this use image_picker in the background.
with that you cant set how many image the user can pick

Comment: Thank you. i decided to use the photo manager library and loaded the images as Uint8List files. i was using File fetching before and that was making it load slower but now it's all good.